# Converting 2D Dataframe to Multidimensional Tensor in Tensorflow (or Tensorly)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorly

I'm very new to python and am trying my hand at higher dimension tensor decomposition techniques.  But first I need to convert my dataframe from a 2D array into a multidimensional tensor and I'm kind of stuck on how to do it.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Subject Cz  F7  F8...Pz Diagnosis Test  Time 
1       #   #   #    #    A        x     100 
1       #   #   #    #    A        x     200   
1       #   #   #    #    A        y     100
1       #   #   #    #    A        y     200
2       #   #   #    #    B        x     100
2       #   #   #    #    B        x     200
2       #   #   #    #    B        y     100
2       #   #   #    #    B        y     200
```

And I would like to convert this to a rank 3 tensor with:

```
Dimension 1: Channel (Cz F7 F8...Pz)
Dimension 2: Test    (x y)
Dimension 3: Time    (100 200)

and also turn Diagnosis into a predictor label
```

I don't think I can just do a `label = df.pop('Diagnosis')` because of the way the dataframe is set up, correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy and simple way you can use tf.reshape to convert 2-D array to n-dimensional array.

**Example**

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = [[1, 2],
     [4, 5],
     [3,4],
     [6,7]]
print(tf.shape(t).numpy())

tf.reshape(t, [2, 2, 2])
```

**Output**

```
[4 2]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[3, 4],
        [6, 7]]], dtype=int32)>
```